# XML schema with header then choice of items

Tags: xsd

I want to create an XML schema that forces a header followed by any of several items.  In other words, this is valid.  `<header>` must always be the first item, but then A and B can be in any order.

```
<root>
  <header/>
  <A/>
  <B/>
  <A/>
  <B/>
</root>
```

My understanding is that I can allow A and B to be in any order with the following.

```
<xs:element name="root">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="A"/>
      <xs:element ref="B"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But how do I force the first element to be `<header>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups can nest in content models, just as parenthesized expressions can nest in regular expressions.  At the outer level, you want a `header` element followed by a mix of `A` and `B` elements.  So use an `xs:sequence` to specify that sequence.

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="root"/>
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="A"/>
      <xs:element ref="B"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```